# unable to print line break in bash script when it begins a string

Tags: string, bash

I'm having trouble printing a string that has multiple lines in bash. When I run this script, everything prints on one line

```
#!/bin/bash
content=""
for ((i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)); do
  content=$'\n'"${content}""${i}"
done
echo "${content}"
```

But if I change it to this, then everything prints on multiple lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
content=""
for ((i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)); do
  content="${content}""${i}"$'\n'
done
echo "${content}"
```

Why does putting `$'\n'` at the end work, but not at the beginning?

Comment: Try using echo -e

Comment: `content=$'\n'"${content}""${i}"` is also working fine but you're always prefixing a line break at the start only.

Comment: on your first script, content will be `\n\n\n...012345...`. On your second script, content will be `0\n1\n2\n...`. They do different things, but both are working and printing newlines.

Comment: Title and question look wrong and misleading. Your first script *does* print all the line breaks at the beginning of the string. If this is not the case on your computer, then you should provide us with an exact copy of your output and what you expected instead.

Comment: BTW `content+="${i}"$'\n'` and `content+=$'\n'"${i}"` both should to work fine

Answer (score 2):

Variables in bash act like buffers, `\n` before variable will concatenate the escape characters first and only after that will concatenate string as it is. In first way that you mentioned echo will output `\n` (special characters) first and only after that the concatenation itself. Because what you are telling to bash is ***"put all special characters in buffer, concatenate string and then print buffer and string together*"**.

In first example that I write below you can concatenate in buffer even the special characters like `\n` in a way that you expected. Putting `\n` in the end will tell echo interpreter that we have some special characters in our text stored in some variable. It can interpret in this manner because of `-e` option and only in this case a variable is seen as a variable in bash. Otherwise it act like I sad before, like a buffer.

Your `content` variable function act like a buffer and it should printed out properly. In your case you want new lines before each line. So, all you have to do is to enable echo command to interpret new lines when you print the buffer. Thus you can use `echo -e` option and further more `echo -ne` when you have string concatenation with `\n` in the end of the line.

If you like to buffer such an output you can use a code like this:

```
content=$(
   clear
   for ((i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)); do
     echo "\n${i}"
   done
)

echo -ne "${content}"
```

After all, this is how your script should be using string concatenations:

```
#!/bin/bash

content=""
for ((i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)); do
  content="${content}${i}\n"
done
echo -ne "${content}"
```

In this case bash understand content as a variable and not as a buffer.

Comment: Hi Mara, welcome to Stack Overflow. In addition to providing the "right" way of doing things, you should explain *why* it's right, *and* answer OP's question. In this case, your answer is functionally equivalent to OP's second version of the script, and does not appear to answer his question.